# Си++. Поиск явных приведений типов в стиле Си: a = (int)b;

Tags: статический-анализ, c, c++

Вопрос по пользе диагностики.
Один человек предложил реализовать в анализаторе [PVS-Studio](http://www.viva64.com/ru/pvs-studio/) поиск всех явных приведений типов в стиле Си. Т.е. выявлять конструкции вида:

`int *x = (int *)y;
float a = float(b);
float c = (float)(d);`

Цель - заменить ве эти приведения на более безопасные варианты - reinterpret_cast/static_cast/const_cast. В процессе подобного рефакторинга вполне могут быть выявлены некоторые дефекты.

Конечно, это не выявление настоящих ошибок. И если эта диагностика будет реализоана, то будет находится в разделе [Customer's Specific Requests] и по умолчанию отключена.

Однако даже в пользе такого варианта, я не уверен. Решил задать вопрос. Нужно кому-то еще искать все явные приведения типов в стиле Си? Захочет кто-то заняться подобным рефакторингом своего кода?

Comment: Я считаю, это осмысленно.

Answer (score 1):

есть разные варианты такого приведения.
1) бессмысленные

```
float d = 3;
float c = (float)(d);
```

для этих стоит предлагать просто убрать.

2) по требованию апи. Это когда некая внешняя функция объявлена с одним типом, а в коде имеем другой тип и делаем насильно приведение, хотя можно было сразу объявить правильно.

3) преобразования, которые не нужны - это когда приводимое выражение гарантированно влазит в результат. (например char в int).

Но главное, что бы после любого совета PVS-Studio код компилировался на максимальном уровне придирчивости компилятора.